# Apache2 crashs with segmentation fault after executing commande apache2 reload

Tags: apache, lxml, mod-wsgi

We are using lxml in several of our applications with Python 2.6 and from time to time, the application stops responding after a segmentation fault error.
I've found a way to "trigger" the issue everytime. If I use apache reload command the issue occurs.
I have checked memory consumption but everything looks fine plenty of memory available.
When I restart apache using apache2 restart, I got no more segmentation fault error.
Batcktrace retrieved from error log:

```
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: *** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/apache2: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f6468bf2c00 ***
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: ======= Backtrace: =========
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /lib/libc.so.6(+0x78bf6)[0x7f64767ecbf6]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2(xmlCopyError+0xd1)[0x7f6473311801]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2(__xmlRaiseError+0x30b)[0x7f6473312ecb]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2(+0x393e5)[0x7f64733173e5]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2(xmlParseDocument+0x2dc)[0x7f647332e5cc]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2(+0x50895)[0x7f647332e895]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so(+0x8cbc2)[0x7f645691cbc2]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so(+0x2c7cf)[0x7f64568bc7cf]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so(+0xb9e29)[0x7f6456949e29]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so(+0xba4dd)[0x7f645694a4dd]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so(+0xde1d1)[0x7f645696e1d1]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x51a0)[0x7f646e446350]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x920)[0x7f646e448080]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(+0x7e040)[0x7f646e3ce040]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f646e3a0593]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3adf)[0x7f646e444c8f]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x920)[0x7f646e448080]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(+0x7e040)[0x7f646e3ce040]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f646e3a0593]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(+0x61fcf)[0x7f646e3b1fcf]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f646e3a0593]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(+0xb69dc)[0x7f646e4069dc]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f646e3a0593]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x43)[0x7f646e4404b3]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so(+0x12fdb)[0x7f646e813fdb]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so(+0x17eed)[0x7f646e818eed]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0(+0x29eb3)[0x7f6476d41eb3]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x69ca)[0x7f6476b019ca]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f647685e1cd]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: ======= Memory map: ========
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6378d2d000-7f6455c85000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6455c85000-7f6455c86000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6455c86000-7f6456486000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6456486000-7f6456489000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 792872                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_bytesio.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6456489000-7f6456689000 ---p 00003000 08:03 792872                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_bytesio.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6456689000-7f645668a000 r--p 00003000 08:03 792872                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_bytesio.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f645668a000-7f645668b000 rw-p 00004000 08:03 792872                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_bytesio.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f645668b000-7f645668f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 792858                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_fileio.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f645668f000-7f645688e000 ---p 00004000 08:03 792858                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_fileio.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f645688e000-7f645688f000 r--p 00003000 08:03 792858                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_fileio.so


Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775b1000-7f64775b8000 r--s 00000000 08:03 805537                     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775b8000-7f64775ba000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775ba000-7f64775bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775bb000-7f64775bc000 rw-s 00000000 08:03 1442753                    /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.shm.5377 (deleted)
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775bc000-7f64775be000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775be000-7f64775bf000 r--p 0001f000 08:03 8000284                    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775bf000-7f64775c0000 rw-p 00020000 08:03 8000284                    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775c0000-7f64775c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f64775c1000-7f647762f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 787387                     /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f647782f000-7f6477832000 r--p 0006e000 08:03 787387                     /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6477832000-7f6477835000 rw-p 00071000 08:03 787387                     /usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f6477835000-7f6477838000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7f647914c000-7f64796e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7fff32855000-7fff32878000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: 7fff3287e000-7fff3287f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Apr 15 15:24:48 server httpd: [Tue Apr 15 15:24:48 2014] [notice] child pid 6126 exit signal Aborted (6)`  

Library version:
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('Python',           sys.version_info))
Python              : (2, 6, 5, 'final', 0)
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('lxml.etree',       etree.LXML_VERSION))
lxml.etree          : (2, 3, 5, 0)
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxml used',      etree.LIBXML_VERSION))
libxml used         : (2, 7, 6)
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxml compiled',  etree.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION))
libxml compiled     : (2, 7, 6)
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxslt used',     etree.LIBXSLT_VERSION))
libxslt used        : (1, 1, 26)
    print("%-20s: %s" % ('libxslt compiled', etree.LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION))
libxslt compiled    : (1, 1, 26)
Apache 2.2.14
```

Do you have any ideas to fix the issue with reload?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are running your web application in the main Python interpreter context and not a sub interpreter. The lxml library is known not to work in sub interpreters properly with it possibly causing the process to crash.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Multiple_Python_Sub_Interpreters

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have checked the provided link. In my case, each application uses it own daemon_process. WSGIDaemonProcess dameon1 threads=25 python-path=/opt/appengine/google_appengine:/opt/appengine/google_appengine/lib/django:/opt/appengine/google_appengine/lib/webob:/opt/appengine/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib
  WSGIProcessGroup daemon1. Should I add the directive WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} ? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are correctly delegating your WSGI applications to the separate daemon process groups, then yes, use WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I added WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} to WSGI applications with separate daemon process groups. After reloading apache , I got the error segmentation fault again Apr 23 15:39:52 server httpd: [Wed Apr 23 15:39:52 2014] [notice] child pid 10544 exit signal Segmentation fault (11). Is there something related to child process after reload ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Get a stack trace http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB and verify you are in fact running in daemon mode and main interpreter. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Sub_Interpreter_Being_Used

Comment: I have followed the instrcuctions provided in those links. the application which the issue occurs run in daemon mode and main interpreter (mod_wsgi.process_group = 'daemon1' , mod_wsgi.application_group = '') but there is some applications in the same server web sharing apache instance run in embedded mode. Could those applications have an impact on application which run in daemon process? Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing that occurs in a web application running in embedded mode (Apache child worker process), should be able to affect the daemon mode processes.